# how to parse this table using pandas.read_csv() with regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to regular expression so this question might seem dumb. I have the following table to parse into a pandas dataframe. The first 18 columns are separated by whitespace (I am not sure which whitespace is used here, but I have tried and I am pretty sure it's not a tab), and the 19th column should be parsed as a whole.
[the following picture is what the table looks like in Unix with command less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEUd.png)

My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Path to the output from hmmscan formatted as parsable table')
parser.add_argument('-f', action="store", dest="f", type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()


df = pd.read_csv(args.f, header=None, comment='#', sep='\s{18}')
df.columns = ['targetName','targetAccession','queryName','queryAccession',
          'E-value1','score1','bias1','E-value2', 'score2', 'bias2',
          'exp','reg','clu','ov','env','dom','rep','inc','targetDescription']
```

However, this code only parses the givent table into two columns, producing the following error:

```
[4721 rows x 2 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "countTF.py", line 15, in <module>
'exp','reg','clu','ov','env','dom','rep','inc','targetDescription']
File "/home/yh362/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5080, in 
__setattr__
return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
File "/home/yh362/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 638, in _set_axis
self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
File "/home/yh362/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 155, in set_axis
'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 19 elements
```

I think my reg expression is wrong, but not sure how to write the correct one since I am not familiar with reg expression at all. Hope someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: there are different numbers of spaces between columns so you can't use `\s{18}` which means exactly 18 spaces between every column. You should rather use `\s+` but it may try to split last column in many columns. But values in columns use the same lenght so you could read it as normal text file and slice every value - like `item1 = row[0:20]`, etc.

Comment: maybe you could read it using [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) for fixed-width columns. `read_fwf(..., widths=[..])`

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` doesn't have a parameter to set max columns. 
But you can prepare your file with regex:

```
import re
import argparse
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Path to the output from hmmscan formatted as parsable table')
parser.add_argument('-f', action="store", dest="f", type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

res = []
p = re.compile(r"\s+")
with open(args.f) as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            res.append(p.split(line, maxsplit=18))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['targetName', 'targetAccession', 'queryName', 'queryAccession',
                           'E-value1', 'score1', 'bias1', 'E-value2', 'score2', 'bias2',
                           'exp', 'reg', 'clu', 'ov', 'env', 'dom', 'rep', 'inc', 'targetDescription'],
                  data=res)

print(df)
```